# How to properly add two different versions of a stored procedure to Visual Studio project(s)?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

We have a Visual Studio `.sqlproj` that is used for several customers. There are a few stored procedures that work differently for each customer.

I created separate SQL Server projects for each client, that when build would overwrite procedures that should be changed.

The problem is I cannot reference them to the base project because this raises an error:

> SQL71508: The model already has an element that has the same name

I can just put the scripts into post-deployment but it seems like the worst scenario. Is there a better way to solve this problem and keep the benefits of Visual Studio editor and builder?

Comment: Thats's the job of Git, not Visual Studio. Use different branches per customer. That's how Visual Studio itself works by the way